# Changing GTK+ theme takes several minutes to take effect

Tags: themes

When I do

```
Tweak Tool -> Appearance
change GTK+ theme,
```

it takes several minutes before I see the change. It used to change instantly, on the same computer, running the same installation of Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.